# iterating associative arrays taking too long

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, associative-array

I am having this javascript object which contains city list along with dependency details on state.

```
var cityList = {
'1' : ['CITY_CODE_A','City A', '2','11','2'],
'2' : ['CITY_CODE_B','City B','','11',''],
'3' : ['CITY_CODE_C','City C', '','11','']
};
var stateList = {
'11' : ['STATE_CODE_A', 'State A'],
'12' : ['STATE_CODE_B', 'State B'],
'13' : ['STATE_CODE_C', 'State C'],
'14' : ['STATE_CODE_D', 'State D']
};
```

Depending on the state selected, key is passed to a function which matches the key with the values (index 3 element in array) in the city list and if found forms an option tag of `<select>`. 
Here is the code :

```
$.each(cityList, function(key, value) {
  if(selectedVal == value[3]){
  $("select[id='"+selectid+"']").append('<option value="'+value[0]+'" code="'+key+'">'    +value[1] + '</option>'); 
  }
});
```

Now when this city list grows to 50K records (2 MB) wiz a state has 50K cities (performance testing) the above code takes 2 mins to load the city list dropdown on Windows 7 machine running the code locally. Tried with native `for`/`in`-loop but did not get satisfactory outcome.

Any ideas on how to reduce the time ? Do I need to change the JS object structure?

Comment: working on so many records at a time will take a lot of resources.... if you want to support so many records you need to check paging based solutions

Comment: You are dynamically creating a dropdown with 50K options? What is the point in doing that even if it happened instantaneously?

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Paging based solutions would not work here as there is something to be changed on an action. The list probably would not go that long but 2 mins time to process this object/array is worrysome.

Comment: Your object is loaded in the DOM or loaded via a XHR request ?

Comment: @Jon - Is there any better way to dynamically populate large amount of data?

Comment: @kanika If there are over 50,000 options then you are doing this wrong.  That number needs to be narrowed down A LOT.  As a user, would you even consider using a website that had a dropdown with over 50,000 options in it?  I'd close the browser and find a better website.

Comment: @PaulRad - It will be XHR request..where this structure (city list) will be returned to client and would be processed client side. Archer - Yea, agreed...but there is some data which is huge in number...and has to handled in better way...it is not a website but an application containing tons of master data

Comment: @kanika: The only winning move is not to play. You should switch to a control that enables searching and on-the-fly display of options.

Comment: Why don't you create a "autocomplete" script where the records are returned only if a min chars are typped ?
A cache could be use to sort the results if the user selection is more and more precise. (sry for my english)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Edit: @downvoters, could you explain why you think it's wrong? But first try running [this test](http://jsperf.com/city-list).

If you want to get cities for a particular state you could create a map where state IDs are the key,

```
var cityList = {
   11 : [ ['CITY_CODE_A','City A', '2','11','2'], ['CITY_CODE_B','City B','','11',''] ],
   12 : [ ['CITY_CODE_C','City C', '2','12','2'], ['CITY_CODE_D','City D','','12',''] ]
}
```

Now you only need to iterate over `citylist[ selectedVal ]`

```
$.each(cityList[selectedVal], function(key, value) {
  $("select[id='"+selectid+"']").append('<option value="'+value[0]+'" code="'+key+'">'    +value[1] + '</option>'); 
});
```

To optimize it further you should avoid DOM manipulation (adding `<option>` elements) in a loop, and buffer it instead:

```
var $selectEl = $('<select />');
$.each(cityList[selectedVal], function(key, value) {
  $selectEl.append('<option value="'+value[0]+'" code="'+key+'">'    +value[1] + '</option>'); 
});
$selectEl.attr( 'id', selectid );
$("select[id='"+selectid+"']").replaceWith( $selectEl );
```

Comment: How does that make adding over 50,000 options quicker?

Comment: I makes the **script** quicker because: if the whole list has 50K options, you'd need to iterate, on average, over ~1k elements (50K cities / 50 states), and it makes the DOM manipulation more efficient.

Comment: What you are doing here is definitely *not* avoiding DOM manipulation in a loop.

Comment: @Jon, sorry, typo. Fixed.

Comment: Yes, this is what we thought initially but there are number of combinations by which city list can be returned say like get all cities for a particular district or get all cities for a country.In that case for each combination/criteria a map would be required.

Comment: @pawel: Fixed how? There's still a `$selectEl.append()` in there.

Comment: @Jon but `$selectEl` is not appended to the document, so it's not in the DOM. There's exactly one operation on the DOM: `$("select[id='"+selectid+"']").replaceWith( $selectEl );`

Comment: @pawel: Oh right -- I read "DOM manipulation" as "using DOM API", not as the "messing with the DOM tree" that you meant. This is indeed going to be faster, but it's still not an acceptable solution IMO (I didn't vote for it either way).

Comment: @pawel - I tried this, did not change the cityList and the function..just modified the DOM manipulation..and which resulted in much better performance..it is taking around 6 seconds now..good pointers..will try to further reduce the time..thanks for the help :)

Comment: @kanika try ditching jQuery and going native, see this performance test: http://jsperf.com/city-list

Answer (score 0):

I am also a friend of better use of search instead of 50k scrolldown items. But to answer your question I would improve your code by using:

```
var html = '';
$.each(cityList, function (key, value) {
    html += '<option value="' + value[0] + '" code="' + key + '">' + value[1] + '</option>'
});

$("select[id='1']").append(html);
```

This will speed up your `option` creation a lot because the DOM will only be changed one time, not 50k times like you said in your example. ([Short Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bJerm/2/))

Comment: Thanks for your answer...yea I tried a similar way mentioned by Pawel..and it has reduced the time to a great extent..thanks for your suggestion :)